# Resource file „obj\project.assets.json” has no result object (?) „.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2”

Tags: c#, cosmos

I've created barebones kernel (Didn't change anything in template, just hit compile after creating project) and project doesnt compile:

```
Resource file „Projects\SQDos\obj\project.assets.json” has no result object (?) „.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2”
```

I have everything that I need installed. Why do I get this error? Quick peek on project.assets.json:

```
"targets": {
    ".NETStandard,Version=v1.5": {
```

Before, VS asked me to install .NET Core SDK at least v 2.0. I've installed v2.1.4. Error comes from .NET Core SDK v2.1.4:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\Microsoft.Net.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(167,5): error
```

What should I do to fix this error? I've tried to translate error message, if anyone would (propably would) do it better, here it is:

```
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\Microsoft.Net.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(167,5): error : Plik zasobów „C:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SQDOS\obj\project.assets.json” nie ma obiektu docelowego dla „.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2”. Upewnij się, że uruchomiono przywracanie i że w elemencie TargetFrameworks dla projektu uwzględniono element „net462”.
2>Kompilowanie projektu „SQDOSBoot.Cosmos” wykonane — NIEPOWODZENIE.
```

EDIT: I've also tried to change .cosmos file to match v1.5 but visual studio goes crazy with no redistributable for this version.